# ServerSocket.accept() doesn't works in second time

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I'm beginer in android and i'm trying develop a connection TCP server.

I have this class:

```
public class JavaTCPServer {


public static void send(String aMessage) {

    final String msg = aMessage;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {

                ServerSocket serverSocket = GlobalSingleton.getInstance().getServerSocket();

                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                printWriter.println(msg);

                printWriter.flush();
                printWriter.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                if (socket != null) {
                    try {

                        socket.close();
                        socket = null;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();

}


}


private ServerSocket serverSocket; //Created in GlobalSingleton Class...


try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constantes.TCP_PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can send message normally in the first time, but when i try to send message the second time the software remains in line: `socket = serverSocket.accept();` and the message in `printWriter.println(msg)` is not sent.

**Additional Information**

When i kill the app in settings and open i can send once.

Any questions don't hesitate ask me.

Thanks for all!

Comment: While it may not be your problem, realize that your code requires a client to initiate a connection each time you want to send a message - effectively it assumes that there is a client repeatedly trying to connect in an endless loop.  Is that really what you want?  Or do you want to send messages through a persistent connection, or perhaps even be the one to initiate connections to the other end?

Comment: Exactly! There are a client in loop trying to connect with the server. And i (as server) will send message to client disconect... Did you understand?

Comment: Can i initialize a TCPClient and server together? In the same port? For example: TCPServer to receive messages and TCPClient to send?

Comment: Typically both clients and servers transmit messages.  The distinction is between who *connects* and who *listens* and *accepts*.  It seems like you might have written your program based on some confusion about those roles.

Comment: I understood. To be more clear... The Client that connect in my app android is a hardware for home automation. And it must works this way: I send UDP Packet saying "Entering in TCP Mode" and the hardware will enter in this mode and i will send TCP messages. After i send all messages i'll send TCP message saying: "EXIT TCP MODE" and the hardware will close your connection with the app android. Was i clear?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG6ztfieQL4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

I wrote my class as the follow bellow code:

```
public class JavaTCPServer {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private String message;
    private Handler updateConversationHandler;
    private Thread serverThread = null;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ServerSocket getServerSocket() {
        return serverSocket;
    }

    public void setServerSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public JavaTCPServer() {

        setUpdateConversationHandler(new Handler());
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    public Handler getUpdateConversationHandler() {
        return updateConversationHandler;
    }

    public void setUpdateConversationHandler(Handler updateConversationHandler) {
        this.updateConversationHandler = updateConversationHandler;
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constantes.TCP_PORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(
                            socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;
        private BufferedReader input;
        private String messageSend;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {
                this.setInput(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        this.clientSocket.getInputStream())));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                Central central = GlobalSingleton.getInstance()
                        .get_current_central();

                if (central != null) {

                    if ((central.getStep() <= central.getObjetivo()) &&
                       (central.getStep() == 99)){

                        try {

                            messageSend = getMessage();

                            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(
                                    clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                            printWriter.println(messageSend);
                            printWriter.flush();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            printWriter.println(Constantes.EXIT_CONFIG);
                            printWriter.flush();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        central.setStep(central.getStep() + 1);
                    }
                }

                /*
                 * try { String read = input.readLine();
                 * updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read)); }
                 * catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }
        }

        public BufferedReader getInput() {
            return input;
        }

        public void setInput(BufferedReader input) {
            this.input = input;
        }
    }

}
```

With this class you can send and receive tcp messages all the time.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You did exactly what I said in my answer. I don't call that solving your own problem.

Comment: And providing and accepting your own answer and misattributing the credit for it is hardly likely to entice people to continue helping you here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only accepts one connection, processes it, and then exits. It does not behave as you have described.

You need a loop.

You also need to start a separate thread to handle each connection.

And calling a method that accepts connections `send()` is inside out and back to front.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @EJP, but i'm a begginer in android... If possible, can you give me a example about your answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would disagree - as far as I can see, this code ends up getting called each time the poster wants to send a message, and their complaint is that it only works the first time.  In particular, if this code were not being called again, then it couldn't be getting stuck at the accept() call in the middle of this code as it is reported to.  That said, it is a little odd that they are expecting somebody to connect to them each time they want to send a message - odd, but not unworkable if the *other end* attempts to connect in a loop.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's why I said it is inside out and bad to front.

Comment: @pedro.olimpio If your question isn't completely self-contained here, it is not valid for this site. Nobody is going to waste their time viewing YouTube videos, which in any case are a poor medium for expressing software intent. Your solution agrees exactly with what I recommended above. The unexplained downvotes baffle me.

Answer (score -1):

Serversocket.accept() function is for accepting a new client and connecting with the client, for messages you need to use DataInputStream() and DataOutputStream()  after connecting with the server. This happens because for the first time server accepts the new client and process further but after this it does not get a new connection and it waits for new connection at serversocket.accept().

Comment: Ok. I tried to do different form here, but can you explain what is the problem when software "freeze" in `Serversocket.accept()` in the first time?

Comment: i guess it hangs because you have not used a `while(true)` loop use a while true loop so that it accepts multiple connections.

Comment: Maintaining a connection to push further messages over would indeed be a more normal course of action, but it's as yet unclear if the asker is doing things the way they are out of inexperience or out of a specific need for an unconventional scheme.

Comment: You don't need to use `DataInputOutputStreams` unless you need the extra APIs. He doesn't. The code in the question reads and writes lines.